# Not able to reload redis cache in superset using celery

Tags: apache-superset

I am new to superset. I have created few dashboards and have cached data using redis. I am trying to reload cache using celery jobs. celery worker runs successfully but cache is not reloaded.
PFA screenshot for

1. celery config
2. celery worker success
3. superset terminal errors when celery job runs.
4. Flask-SQLalchemy is already installed

Does anyone have idea how to fix this?
I just want to reload data in the cache

[celery config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPAiy.png)

[celery worker success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBPI7.png)

[superset terminal errors when celery job runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZm18.png)

[Flask-SQLalchemy is already installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUcUv.png)

Comment: Please post the code as a text, not a screenshot.

Comment: @toyotaSupra Terminal do not allow copying from it and pasting outside it.